# ReturnURL opening in iFrame instead of reloading page

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal Pros iframe implementation and all is working fine...

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
<form style="display:none;" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb?cmd=_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50.00">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="KASDFS323234">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="text" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['email_address']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mydomain.com/notify.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mydomain.com/thankyou">
</form>
```

My problem is that the return URL of www.mydomain.com/thankyou is opening up inside of the iframe instead of reloading the browser with that page.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: That's because you're in an IFRAME to start with.

Comment: I understand that, but up until today it wasn't a problem.  That's what I can't understand

Comment: Up until today were you in an IFRAME to start with?